# Benefit cost analysis software

Tags: software-rec

I was wondering if anyone knows about a benefit cost analysis software geared towards transportation projects. I use microBENCOST, but it's old and buggy.

[MicroBENCOST SUMMARY](http://www.dot.ca.gov/hq/tpp/offices/ote/benefit_cost/models/microbencost.html).

if you have ever done benefit / cost analysis, what softwre did you use and would you recommend it?

Comment: Well this explains all the traffic problems, if upgrades are analyzed with ancient DOS apps!  =)

Comment: what happens is that engineers got taught a software, get comfortable with it, and then are reluctant to change what they're used too

Comment: This question went through three revisions, but it clearly is asking for a recommendation, confused by this question honestly

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you research Excel spreadsheets or templates.  I had an operations class for my MBA and we used Excel to calculate least cost transportation routing using Excel.

**Edit**
Here is an example:

http://www.th.gov.bc.ca/publications/planning/Tools/081203_Shortben.xls

Comment: certainly Excel can be used for this - just like it can be for a huge variety of other tasks.. but it's not a dedicated tool :-|

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand how microBENCOST does the calculations or is this something that you are not usre about. There are programmes designed to do similar calculations but they may not use the same methodology as microBENCOST so it's important you understand how the calculations are carried out in order to do an appropriate comparison.

I have do extensive cost benefit analyses before in Excel and I know of at least two cases where an automated product based on VB and Excel have been produced for clients to undertake standardised cost benefit analyses, although I may not recomend this approach myself.